# why Page is getting reloaded after put method call on json server

Tags: angular, json-server

**why Page is getting reloaded after calling put method on json-server**

Component.ts file  using ngModelChange, on every click there will be service call, when I click on check box data is getting updated in server but, page is getting reloaded on service call. I would like to prevent page reload .

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div class="group-gap">
        <h5 class="mb-3">Partner Type</h5>
        <div class="d-block my-3 checkbox-column">
          <label formArrayName="partners" (change)="viewPartner(partners[i].name)" *ngFor="let partner of form.controls.partners.controls; let i = index">
            <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i"> {{partners[i].name}}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- ================== Partner 1 START ========================= -->
  <div *ngIf="partner1_content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h3>Partner1</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-content">

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id="accordionPartner1">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="partnerhead">
                    <h3 class="mb-0">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#partner1">
                           Partner
                            <small>Manager</small>
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse show" id="partner1" data-parent="#accordionPartner1">

                    <div class="card-body">
                      <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="partner1.partnerManager[0].addPartner" (ngModelChange) = "updatePartner1(partner1)" data-md-icheck /> Add Partner
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                     </label>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <div id="accordionuser">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="userhead">
                    <h3 class="mb-0">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user1">
                            User
                            <small>Manager</small>
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse show" id="user1" data-parent="#accordionuser">
                    <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let user of partner1.UserManager | keyvalue, let i = index;">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="user.value" (click) = "updatePartner1()" data-md-icheck /> {{user.key}}
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                          </label>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div id="accordionProject1">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="projecthead">
                      <h3 class="mb-0">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#project1">
                             Projects
                              <!-- <small>Manager</small> -->
                          </a>
                      </h3>
                  </div>

                  <div class="collapse show" id="project1" data-parent="#accordionProject1">
                      <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let project of partner1.Projects | keyvalue, let i = index;">
                          <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="project.value" (click) = "updatePartner1()" data-md-icheck /> {{project.key}}
                              <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                      </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div id="accordionkb">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="userhead">
                      <h3 class="mb-0">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#kb1">
                              Knowledge Base
                              <!-- <small>Manager</small> -->
                          </a>
                      </h3>
                  </div>

                  <div class="collapse show" id="kb1" data-parent="#accordionkb">
                      <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let kb of partner1.KnowledgeBase | keyvalue, let i = index;">
                          <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="kb.value" (click) = "updatePartner1()" data-md-icheck /> {{kb.key}}
                              <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                      </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
            <h2>Permitions1</h2>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                              <!-- Following headers are rotated -->
                              <th class="rotate">
                                <div>
                                  <span>Type</span>
                                </div>
                              </th>
                              <th class="rotate">
                                <div>
                                  <span>View</span>
                                </div>
                              </th>
                              <th class="rotate">
                                <div>
                                  <span>Edit</span>
                                </div>
                              </th>
                              <th class="rotate">
                                <div>
                                  <span>None</span>
                                </div>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody *ngFor="let items of partner1.Permistion">
                            <tr *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue, let i = index;">
                              <td class="row-header" >{{item.key}}</td>

                              <!-- This need to dynamic fixt it later-->
                              <td>
                                <input type="radio"  name="inlineRadioOprions"  [value]="item.value.view"  id="inlineRadio1"/>

                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <input type="radio"  name="inlineRadioOprions"  [value]="item.value.edit"  id="inlineRadio2"/>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOprions"  [value]="item.value.none" id="inlineRadio3"/>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ================== Partner 1 END =========================== -->

</div>




<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> Function to call Service method.

```
        import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { PratnerService } from '../../../../services/pratner.service';
import { PartnersDataModel, PartnerModel, PartnerMangerModel } from './../../../../shared/partner.model';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, FormControl } from '../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-partner',
  templateUrl: './partner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./partner.component.css']
})
export class PartnerComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  partners = [];
  partnerData: PartnerModel[];
  partner1: PartnerModel;
  partner2: PartnerModel;
  partner3: PartnerModel;
  partner4: PartnerModel;
  partner1_content: boolean;
  partner2_content: boolean;
  partner3_content: boolean;
  partner4_content: boolean;
  p1ItemList: any[];

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private partnerService: PratnerService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      partners: new FormArray([])
    });
    this.partnerService.getPartnerTypes().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);

        this.partnerData = data;
        console.log("Data from service" , this.partnerData[0]);
        this.partner1 = this.partnerData[0];
        this.partner2 = this.partnerData[1];
        this.partner3 = this.partnerData[2];
        this.partner4 = this.partnerData[3];
       console.log(this.partner1);
      }

    )

    this.partners = this.getOrders();
    this.addCheckboxes();
  }

  viewPartner($event) {

    this.partner1_content = this.form.value.partners[0];
    this.partner2_content = this.form.value.partners[1];
    this.partner3_content = this.form.value.partners[2];
    this.partner4_content = this.form.value.partners[3];

 }


  private addCheckboxes() {
    this.partners.map((o, i) => {
      const control = new FormControl(false); // if first item set to true, else false
      (this.form.controls.partners as FormArray).push(control);
    });
  }

  getOrders() {
    return [
      { id: 100, name: 'Partner 1' },
      { id: 200, name: 'Partner 2' },
      { id: 300, name: 'Partner 3' },
      { id: 400, name: 'Partner 4' }
    ];
  }



  updatePartner1(p){
    this.partnerService.updatePartnerTypes(p)
    .subscribe(
       (data) => {
         this.partner1 = data
        console.log(data)
      });
  }



  setradio(a, options){
    console.log(a, options);
  }

}
```

This is the service call on json-server

```
updatePartnerTypes(partnerdata:PartnerModel):Observable<PartnerModel>{
  console.log("In service ...", partnerdata)
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  };
  return this.http.put<PartnerModel>(baseURL + 'partner/'+partnerdata.id, partnerdata, httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
}
```

Comment: Its impossible to say `WHY` as there is no code of component in your shared code. Please share the component code . There is something more than just a service call, that's for sure

Comment: I have updated the post with component

Comment: You have way too much code, especially in the html. Please provide a [mcve], with the **minimal** code to reproduce the issue.